# Finding the smallest subtree

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-theory, subtree

Given a graph of n nodes that are all interconnected on a coordinate plane, what's the best way to find a subtree of minimal distance that contains m nodes?

The only solution I've found to this problem is to generate all combinations of the nodes to connect and attempt to connect these nodes via either Kruskal's or Prim's algorithm while disregarding the rest, then compare all trees created and find the smallest one, but this isn't exactly efficient when it comes to larger trees.

Is there a faster, more efficient algorithm/method?

Comment: I don't get the terms you use in this question. Does the nodes have values you want to have the smallest summed up for or is it the edges that has values? And is m the given amount, or a fixed set of nodes?

Comment: The edges have values where the weight is the distance between them on the coordinate plane.

m is an arbitrary number such that m <= n.

Comment: Can edge weights be negitive? Can there be negitive weight cycles?

Comment: @JSmyth: Since the edge weights are distances, no, there will not be any negative weight cycles.

@Rob: The tree is created from the graph.  Not every edge connecting the m nodes are used, only the ones composing the MST containing the m nodes, in my solution, generated from Prim's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are asking about the [K-minimum spanning tree (k-MST)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-minimum_spanning_tree) problem, which is known to be NP-complete.  So you're not going to do much better than your current algorithm.

However, in the comments, you say that your graph is generated from a coordinate plane, so I can only assume that you have some geometric information about the nodes in the graph.  The [WWW compendium entry](http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/node71.html) mentions that you can use a polynomial-time approximation scheme for Euclidean k-MST.  This paper describes one:

> Arora, Sanjeev. (1996), [Polynomial time
>   approximation scheme for Euclidean TSP
>   and other geometric problems](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~arora/pubs/tsp.ps), In
>   *Proceedings of the 37th Ann. IEEE Symp. on Foundations of Computer
>   Science*, pages 2-11.

They mention k-MST directly in there, so I think you could try that algorithm if you really want more speed.